# Rails implementation for securing S3 documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, amazon-s3, obfuscation

I would like to protect my s3 documents behind by rails app such that if I go to:

www.myapp.com/attachment/5 that should authenticate the user prior to displaying/downloading the document.

I have read similar questions on stackoverflow but I'm not sure I've seen any good conclusions.

From what I have read there are several things you can do to "protect" your S3 documents.

1) Obfuscate the URL.  I have done this.  I think this is a good thing to do so no one can guess the URL.  For example it would be easy to "walk" the URL's if your S3 URLs are obvious:  https://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp.com/attachments/1/document.doc.  Having a URL such as: 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp.com/7ca/6ab/c9d/db2/727/f14/document.doc seems much better.
This is great to do but doesn't resolve the issue of passing around URLs via email or websites.

2) Use an expiring URL as shown here:  [Rails 3, paperclip + S3 - Howto Store for an Instance and Protect Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897837/rails-3-paper-clip-s3-howto-store-for-an-instance-and-protect-access)
For me, however this is not a great solution because the URL is exposed (even for just a short period of time) and another user could perhaps in time reuse the URL quickly.  You have to adjust the time to allow for the download without providing too much time for copying.  It just seems like the wrong solution.

3) Proxy the document download via the app.  At first I tried to just use send_file:  http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right   but the problem is that these files can only be static/local files on your server and not served via another site (S3/AWS).  I can however use send_data and load the document into my app and immediately serve the document to the user.  The problem with this solution is obvious - twice the bandwidth and twice the time (to load the document to my app and then back to the user).

I'm looking for a solution that provides the full security of #3 but does not require the additional bandwidth and time for loading.  It looks like Basecamp is "protecting" documents behind their app (via authentication) and I assume other sites are doing something similar but I don't think they are using my #3 solution.

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I went with a 4th solution:

4) Use amazon bucket policies to control access to the files based on referrer:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingBucketPolicies.html

**UPDATE AGAIN:**

Well #4 can easily be worked around via a browsers developer's tool.  So I'm still in search of a solid solution.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to do two things:

1. Make the bucket and all objects inside it private. The naming convention doesn't actually matter, the simpler the better.
2. Generate signed URLs, and redirect to them from your application. This way, your app can check if the user is authenticated and authorized, and then generate a new signed URL and redirect them to it using a 301 HTTP Status code. This means that the file will never go through your servers, so there's no load or bandwidth on you. Here's the docs to presign a GET_OBJECT request:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for number 3 it is the only truly secure approach. Because once you pass the user to the S3 URL that is valid till its expiration time. A crafty user could use that hole the only question is, will that affect your application? 
Perhaps you could set the expire time to be lower which would minimise the risk?
Take a look at an excerpt from this post:
[Accessing private objects from a browser](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/)

> All private objects are accessible via
>   an authenticated GET request to the S3
>   servers. You can generate an
>   authenticated url for an object like
>   this:

```
S3Object.url_for('beluga_baby.jpg', 'marcel_molina')
```

> By default
>   authenticated urls expire 5 minutes
>   after they were generated.
>
> Expiration options can be specified
>   either with an absolute time since the
>   epoch with the :expires options, or
>   with a number of seconds relative to
>   now with the :expires_in options:

Comment: Thank you for the post.  Isn't that my #2 solution?  I know that it's viable but it just seems like it's not a truly secure approach.  For some reason I feel like it leaves a hole (even if it is rather small).  Any suggestions on how to implement my #3 without the double bandwidth issue?

Comment: Well its as close to secure as you can get. You might be able to use a reverse proxy of some sort to get this but bandwidth is gonna be used somewhere with this. I would just set the timeout to 1 min.

Comment: I was hoping that I was missing some solution related to some apache plugin where it can redirect based on auth from RoR.  Doesn't the timeout (no matter how small of a window you try to set) still allow some level of insecurity?....but nonetheless I agree that this may just be the only 2 answers.  If no one else chimes in I'll set yours as the correct answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah but even with the redirect the user gets sent to the S3 url. If you dont redirect then you are moving bits from S3 to your server then to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in the process of trying to do something similar for quite sometime now. If you dont want to use the bandwidth twice, then the only way that this is possible is to allow S3 to do it. Now I am totally with you about the exposed URL. Were you able to come up with any alternative?

I found something that might be useful in this regard - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempFederationTokenRuby.html

Once a user logs in, an aws session with his IP as a part of the aws policy should be created and then this can be used to generate the signed urls. So in case, somebody else grabs the URL the signature will not match since the source of the request will be a different IP. Let me know if this makes sense and is secure enough.