# Is it possible fora user temporarily upload a file to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip, uploading

I want to upload monthly .xls sheets for my clients to download. It has come to my attention that heroku doesn't allow writing files. I don't want to use paperclip or S3 because the data is a tad sensitive (and I want the upcoming ones to overwrite the old ones).

Is paperclip\S3 my only option or is there a way to allow heroku to store some files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399149/rails-implementation-for-securing-s3-documents

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897837/rails-3-paperclip-s3-howto-store-for-an-instance-and-protect-access?lq=1

Comment: Do not try to use the heroku filesystem because it is just not a good idea. See the links above for others with the same issue as you have.

Comment: Well, the kicker is that I CANNOT store data on S3. Or anywhere else. It's gotta be local. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Read the details here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem. Note that every time you deploy, or switch dynos you will lose the files. Maybe you should look into other hosting options.

Comment: Wizard, you should add that as an asnwer.

Comment: Any luck getting your problem sorted out?

Comment: No, not really, but I think we shouldn't be doing it that way anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Read the details here devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem. Note that every time you deploy, or switch dynos you will lose the files. Maybe you should look into other hosting options.