# Set Up Route for Accessing Private S3 Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I've been following
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3
and
[Rails 3, paperclip + S3 - Howto Store for an Instance and Protect Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897837/rails-3-paper-clip-s3-howto-store-for-an-instance-and-protect-access) to try and get Paperclip's expiring links to work. I believe most of what I'm running into is one of the routing variety.

In my pieces_controller I put a method in like this

```
def download
   redirect_to @asset.asset.expiring_url(1000)
end
```

And then in my routes, I put this:

```
 match "pieces/download"
```

Then in my view I have:

```
 <%= link_to download_asset_path(piece)%>
```

It would seem to be far from working, and I'm not sure what is messed up. I know I'm getting routing errors for one, but it's also telling me that my download_asset_path is undefined, which is likely also routing related... I feel like I'm doing everything all wrong.

Tearing my hair out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your routes file to:

```
match 'pieces/download' => 'pieces#download', :as => 'download_asset'
```

Your match needs to tell which controller#action to go to, and the as option will allow you to name the route download_asset_path.

If your pieces controller is for a Piece resource it could be cleaner like:

```
resources :pieces do
  member do
    get :download
  end
end
```

But then you would want to change the link to:

```
link_to 'Link text', download_piece_path(piece)
```

For further reading:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: That route definitely made the difference in things working at all, thank you so much! I've been reading and re-reading that routing guide, but I think it's a bit much to digest all at once. The bit you have there about the piece controller doesn't immediately make sense to me, that doesn't generate an expiring url does it? And thanks! I'm going to mark this one as resolved as soon as it all makes sense to me, and I can fill in the blanks.

Comment: No it doesn't generate the expiring url.  That's what your doing in your controller action.  What it does do is create the named route download_piece_path, which gets mapped to the proper controller and action so that you are able to serve up the asset.  Your route file is used to tell your application which controllers & actions can be accessed, and generates the named route helpers for you.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! That was very helpful, I just managed to get it working. There were a few other stumbling points so I'm going to go ahead an post some more specifics on what worked for me.