# Using Paperclip expiring_url with S3 :permission => :private

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am creating a Rails app where a User uploads a file to S3 using Paperclip and which then a separate group can download the uploaded files. I need the files to be private and have been trying to use :permissions => :private without any luck, but can upload and download files in a with this turned off.

I have been following the github issue: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3 and [Rails 3, paperclip + S3 - Howto Store for an Instance and Protect Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897837/rails-3-paperclip-s3-howto-store-for-an-instance-and-protect-access) but am still stuck and would appreciate some help. Here is what I have so far:

**model/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts

 ...

  if Rails.env.development?
    has_attached_file :model
  else
    has_attached_file :model,
        :storage => :s3,    
        :path    => "files/:id/:basename.:extension",
        :default_url => '/images/missing_:style.jpg',   
        :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
        :s3_permissions => :private,
        :s3_host_name => 's3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com',
        :s3_credentials => {
            :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
            :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
        }
  end
```

**user_controller.rb**

```
 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @part = Part.new
    if @user.save
      ...
    end
  end

  def download
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(@user.model.expiring_url(10))
  end
```

**part_controller.rb**

```
class PartsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @parts = Part.all
    @users = User.all
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 match 'users/download' => 'users#download', :as => 'download_model'
```

**parts/index.html.erb**

```
<p>
<% @parts.each do |part| %>
    <p><%= part.model_name %></p>
<% end %>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <p><%= link_to "Download", download_model_path(user) %></p>
<% end %>

</p>
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? `if Rails.env.development?
    has_attached_file :model
  else`

Comment: What is a problem? What do you mean by 'separate group'?

Comment: Here's a walkthrough and accompanying source code for using authenticated URLs: https://medium.com/@carlosramireziii/secure-file-download-urls-in-rails-d52128b24311#.tubaua8va 

Most of your code looks the same. What's the exact issue that you are seeing?