# Change s3_permissions in runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have Paperclip set to

```
`:s3_permissions => :private`
```

in the initializer.

I want to be able to change specific instances's permission to **public**.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897837/rails-3-paperclip-s3-howto-store-for-an-instance-and-protect-access
also you can use `:s3_permissions => :public_read` to allow r/w permissions for all

Comment: thanks @Gowri that's does it

Comment: Shall I make it as answer then

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
:s3_permissions => :public_read  # to allow r/w permissions for all
```

please check this link for reference:

[Rails 3, paperclip + S3 - Howto Store for an Instance and Protect Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897837/rails-3-paperclip-s3-howto-store-for-an-instance-and-protect-access)